# Django form is not showing

Tags: python, html, django, forms, view

I want to create a simple html login form with django forms, but whenever I run the server the form does not show, only a button.

This is what I have in my `forms.py` file

```
from django import forms

class LogForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.CharField(label='email')
    psword = forms.CharField(label='pasword')
```

Then in `views.py`

```
     from django.shortcuts import render
     from django.http import HttpResponse
     from blog.forms import LogForm

     def get_info(request):
       form = LogForm()
       return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})
```

And finally in `login.html`

```
  <h1>LOGIN PAGE!</h1>

    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

And the only thing that shows is this

[View of the webpage with only the sumbit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfEjZ.png)

Thanks for the help

Comment: try `{{ form.as_p }}`

Comment: Tried that, but it did not work. Thanks, though

Comment: Have you considered using a generic class based view?

Comment: @MarcellErasmus what do you mean by that?

Comment: @TheObands so I tried to replicate the issue with the given code, it is working for me. Can you check your html source code if you can see some input type, and check your css if it is hiding any input type text.

Comment: Django comes with a [login view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#all-authentication-views) you don't need to write your own. As Nalin says, the code you have posted looks ok, so either you've missed out something from your question, or you haven't saved your code/restarted your server so aren't running the code you think you are.

Comment: @NalinDobhal Thanks!!!. I have a base code but that doesn´t seem to be interfering with the html. It still doesn´t show the text fields to sumbit the options. Also, I know django has its own auth system, but I need to do one of my own because the project needs the user to have other attributes that relate to other tables in my database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `FormView`

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class LogForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.CharField(label='email')
    psword = forms.CharField(label='pasword')
```

views.py

```
from myapp.forms import LogForm
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

class LogView(FormView):
    template_name = 'login.html'
    form_class = LogForm
    success_url = '/ /'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # This method is called when valid form data has been POSTed.
        # It should return an HttpResponse.           
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

login.html

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Note if you are writing a custom view you can use this method, read more about this in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview)

Django also has ready packaged views for `authentication` that you can use. You can read more about that [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView)

Comment: I did what you just edited, but it still does not show the text fields.

Comment: Also, I know django has its own authentication system, but I need to do one of my own due to other Attributes the user needs to have for my project